# how to install netbeans 8.1 in ubuntu 14.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu Linux. I have started operating Ubuntu before two days.
I want to install Net-Beans in my machine which has Linux. I have searched for  solutions over the web and then I got this answer-

"Open the Terminal and considering the file is in Downloads folder then do

" chmod +x ~/Downloads/netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh

After that

```
cd ~/Downloads && ./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
```

And that will bring up the Installation Window.

To Uninstall run

```
./uninstall.sh
```

in the install directory"

But this does not resolve my question. Does anyone have an answer ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What errors do you see?

Answer (score 2):

You cna install netbeans from apt-get using :

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly download netbean 8.1 from here

https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=php&bits=x64

Then follow this step.

```
1. chmod u+x netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
2. ./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

Hope this will help you.